# Neo4j: different relationships with the same TYPE name

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Currently, I have a graph which I wanted to add multiple new same types of relationships. However, what I've gotten was the query created unnecessary relationships.

For example:

This is the initial graph

[image]

I wanted to add a new relationship **BELONG_TO** which link from **Request** node to **Item** Node. Notice that the relationship type name **BELONG_TO** has already existed which link **Category** node to **Request** node in the graph.

After execute the query below, This is what I got.

```
MATCH (i:Item), (r:Request)
MERGE (r)-[:BELONG_TO]->(i);
```

[image]

As you can see the query creates extra unnecessary **BELONG_TO** relationships (from Category to Item and from Request to Request). What I wanted is to only create a  **BELONG_TO** relationship which link Request Node to Item Node.

What I wanted:

[image]

Is there any solution for this? 
- The version of neo4j I'm using is 3.5.14
- Each node and relationship does not have any properties in it.

**EDIT:**
Correction made on relationship name as type not label.

Comment: can you please share the output of this query on your graph ? 
 ```MATCH (i:Item) ,(r:Request) RETURN labels(i),labels(r) LIMIT 100```

Comment: @TheTeacher It returns the label names, which is `Item` and `Request`.

Comment: Each node has one label or multiple

Answer (score 2):

1. In neo4j, a **node** has 0 or more "**labels**", and a **relationship** has exactly 1 "**type**" (*NOT* "label").
2. It looks like the node in your visualization with the `Category` label also happens to have the `Request` label, and the node in your visualization with the `Request` label also happens to have the `Item` label. That would explain the behavior you see. If that is not intended, you should [REMOVE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/remove/#remove-remove-a-label-from-a-node) all extraneous labels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you click the node, it will tell you what labels has on the node.
The node which has **Category** also have the label **Request**.